# iPhone - View like SMS Contacts view

Tags: iphone, contacts

I'm trying to implement a view similar to contacts view in iPhone Message (SMS) app.
When composing a message on iPhone, there will be "+" button to add contacts. On click of "+", it will show list of contacts and just by selecting a contact, it will add the contact name in "To" text field. 
I found following code to show contacts. But on click of a contact, its showing more details about the contact and just not selected.

```
    ABPeoplePickerNavigationController* picker;
picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;

CGRect newFrame = picker.view.frame;
newFrame.size.height = newFrame.size.height - 49;
picker.view.frame = newFrame;

[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:NO];
[picker release];
```

Can some body point out me correct way to select a contact?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.
I've to implement the delegate methods to handle that.
The following are the delegate methods

```
- (void)peoplePickerNavigationControllerDidCancel:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker {

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

}

```
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController: (ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
```

{
    .
    .
    .
    .
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

```
return NO;
```

}

```
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person 
                            property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier
```

{
    return NO;
}